# Finder doesn't recognize custom UTI

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uti

I was trying to create a custom UTI for my non-document-based application.
I have already been reading the Apple documents and several SO questions, but none seems to be addressing my issue.

I created a new UTI in XCode 4 ( "Target" --> "Exported UTIs" ), where I set the identifier in a reverse DNS order, a short description and a custom file extension that is not used by the system or anyone else.

[image: This is how it looks in XCode 4]
Unfortunately, Finder does not seem to recognize the UTI, meaning that it is not showing the icon and is not showing the description when I associate the file with my application manually.

Do I have to do something else to make this work?
I am actually just saving these files in a binary format and attaching the custom file extension at the end of the path.
When associated with the application manually, double-clicking a ".vsplf" file results in successfully opening the application and loading the settings from the file.

Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: I found this similar question which helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354680/problem-registering-file-type-through-utis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring the UTI is not sufficient. You also need to create a `Document Type` entry in your Info.plist.
There is a good explanation with screenshots here:

[How to register a custom non-document UTI / file type for OSX to recognize it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636306/how-to-register-a-custom-non-document-uti-file-type-for-osx-to-recognize-it?rq=1)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that ;) I figured that out in the meantime. Still, good to have it here. Maybe others run into the same issue. Thanks!